AGPLv3 license notice adding to each file
So I have added code licensed under AGPLv3 license to my own project. Licensed my own project under AGPLv3 and noticed that there are no code file with license notice included only AGPLv3 license file.
The question is I have MIT licensed code. Can I re-license it to AGPLv3 license and place the notice bellow to each of them, considering the fact that I keep original MIT license file:
 <one line to give the program's name and a brief idea of what it does.>
    Copyright (C) <year>  <name of author>

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published
    by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU Affero General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

And the other question original author of AGPLv3 licensed code seem to have not include this notice for the files in his repository. And since AGPLv3 license file has no author's name and files without license how should i go about those files? As I don't know how to set license notice on them without author's name. If I make changes to the code can I add the AGPLv3 notice from my name? Or what I should do? As I don't want files to just hang unlicensed.
